# Why are undefined points included in concavity notation but not in $f(x)$ increasing/decreasing

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For example $f'(x)$ is undefined at $0$ and $f'(x)<0$ both sides
Then the interval for $f(x)$ decreasing would be $(-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$

but when for example when $f''(x)$ is undefined at $0$ and $f''(x)<0$
Then the interval for concave down would be $(-\infty, \infty)$

Why is this?

Comment: Who says the former?  If I have $f(x) = -3x$ (if $x < 0$), $= 0$ (if $x = 0$), or $= -2x$ (if $x > 0$) then I would have no compunction in saying that $f(x)$ is decreasing over the reals, despite the fact that $f'(x)$ is undefined at $x = 0$.

Comment: By the way, do you mean "concave down" in the second paragraph?

Comment: @BrianTung yup. edited